# PHP-MySQL Listing Data Issues

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

I'm having some listing data issues.

Database Schema :

[image: DB]

Here is my code :

SQL Query :

```
SELECT tblquestions.Question, 
    tblhints.hint, 
    tblhints.pic, 
    tblquestions.Id
FROM tblquestions INNER JOIN tblhints ON tblquestions.GroupId = tblhints.GroupId ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 57
```

It gives an output like:

[image: Output]

in tblquestions the fields recording like :

[image: db data sample]

Php Code  :

```
  <?php

            $i=0;
            $t=0;

            for ($i=0; $i < 57 ; $i++) { 

                while($kayitlar_rs = mysql_fetch_array($kayitlar)) {

                // $toplamkayit = mysql_num_rows($kayitlar);
                $soruGroupId = $kayitlar_rs["GroupId"];
                $hint = $kayitlar_rs["hint"];
                $sorufoto = $kayitlar_rs["pic"];

                // $sorubtntxt = array();
                $sorusql = mysql_query("select * from tblquestions where GroupId=".$soruGroupId);
                while($soruRs = mysql_fetch_array($sorusql)) {
                            $sorubtntxt[] = $kayitlar_rs["Question"];
                }

                // die();
                $i = $i+1;
                $t = $t+1;


?>
```

HTML/DIVs :

```
<div id="soru<?=$i?>">

            <span class="hint hintbg hintyazi">İPUCU: <b class="orange"><?=$hint?></b></span>
            <div class="sorufoto"><img src="../assets/ulke/<?=$sorufoto?>"></div>

            <span class="soruId"><?=$soruId?></span>
            <div id="sorubtn" class="font">
                <div id="soruBtnSol"><a class="sorubtn<?=$i?>" href="#"><span class="sorubtnTxtSol"><?=$sorubtntxt[0]?></span></a></div>
                <div id="soruBtnSag"><a class="sorubtn<?=$t?>" href="#"><span class="sorubtnTxtRight"><?=$sorubtntxt[1]?></span></a></div>
            </div>  
    </div>
```

**What i want to do is :**

1) To get datas from `**tblhints**` and connect them to tblquestions **GroupId** to take records which has same **GroupId** .. Each record has to list **`hint`** , **`pic`** from tblhints. And every single record has two options to list like in the 3th. image (tblquestions). I've tried to do but i couldn't make it.

2) There is also `$i` and `$t` attributes to count every record on my page. `$i` is counting each record, $t for two options which we get from **tblquestions**.

None of them are working properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Anyone have a cooment?

Comment: 1. the code refers to `$kayitlar_rs["GroupId"]` but GroupId is not part of the query's select list. 2. records are fetched into `$soruRs` and then this variable is never used. 3. It's not clear why `$i` is incremented twice. `$t` is `$i/2` so what's the point of having 2 variables?